# Save Image between PIL and CV2

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, opencv

I now want to create an Image,
and put some text on it.

But now I have a question

Here is the code I use

```py
from PIL import Image , ImageDraw , ImageFont
import cv2
import numpy as np
    
#Create a Image
p_image = Image.new('L' , (960 , 720) , 50)
    
# Put text on it
text = 'Hello World\nHello World\nHello World\nHello World\nHello World\nHello World'
draw  = ImageDraw.Draw(p_image)
draw.multiline_text(
    (0 , 0) , 
    text , 
    font = ImageFont.truetype('font.ttf' , size = 16) , 
    fill = 255)
    
# Save it by PIL
p_image.save('1.png')
    
#Convert to CV2 then save it
c_image = np.array(p_image)
cv2.imwrite('2.png' , c_image)
```

Both method turn out to same image

But the size of PIL and cv2 are quite different

The PIL one is 2.27KB

The CV2 one is 5.30KB

Can some one talk me why?

[The picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbSJO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are two different modules that potentially use different versions of different libraries that make different decisions about the best filters and compression to use.

In order to see how the images are saved, try using any of the following commands to inspect the two images:

```
pngcheck -v image.png
exiftool image.png
magick identify -verbose image.png
```

I find it easiest to compare like this:

```
magick identify -verbose a.png > a
magick identify -verbose b.png > b
opendiff a b
```

Comment: Wow, thank you. The question have confused me so much.I think i understand right now